# Cannot load module 'XMPP_Messenger_iOS' as 'xmpp_messenger_ios error in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

I added pod "xmpp-messenger-ios" , but when I run

"Cannot load module 'XMPP_Messenger_iOS' as 'xmpp_messenger_ios'"

appear in swift. How can I solved this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly the issue is over here, but a deep clean in Xcode will solve your problem. To do a deep clean press `Command` + `Shift` + `Alt/Option` + `K`. After this, build it up again using `Command` + `B` or just hit run or `Command` + `R`.

Thank You!